# Difference between the AD8561 and LM393 comparators

Tags: sensor, comparator

I am trying to build a capacitive touch sensor circuit on a breadboard such as the one on this website, http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/Touch-sensor-circuit-with-voltage-comparator.php.

I only have an AD8561 comparator, instead of a LM393 as the one being used in the website. Can I still use the AD8561 to build the capacitive touch sensor? What is the major difference between the two?

Here is the schematic I built with the AD8561. When I plug in the 5V power source the LED turns on and the touch wires do not work.[image: AD8561 schematic]

Comment: The previous question has been deleted?

Comment: What do the datasheets say about the two devices? What voltages does the circuit apply to them? Finally, what does the datasheet say about recommended components or construction, such as bypass capacitors or ground planes?

Comment: The big thing is your 4M7 resistor is connected to ground instead of +5V as in the linked schematic.  Also, you have left the latch pin floating which means it's going to do what it wants, usually whatever is worst for your circuit.

Comment: Frederick - Hi, In future please do not repost an updated version of a question. On this site, "closed question" means "not accepting answers, pending an edit from the question's author (you) to fix whatever is shown in the closure notice on that question". Then the edited question is reviewed for reopening. That is part of the difference on Stack Exchange. Questions should be edited by their authors to improve them, in response to comments e.g. requesting more details. However as there is now an answer here, I won't delete this question. See the [tour] and the [help] for more details. Thanks.

Comment: The common mode input voltage range of 0-3 V may be a problem using AD8561

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AD8561 is a fast comparator with 7ns propagation delay. To get this kind of speed, a few compromises have to be made, and one of them is the input current. It is quite high, typical 3µA coming out of the inputs according to the datasheet. High frequency circuits use low impedances to counter parasitic capacitance, so this is not a problem for the intended use of this chip.

The other is a standard comparator. Its reaction time is 1.5µs, so about 200 times slower than the other, but its input current is 125 times lower, at 25nA.

Since your circuit uses high impedances (megohms) on the input, the fast comparator won't work reliably because it has too much input current. It will probably work if you wet your finger.

There's an error in the schematic: the 4M7 resistor should go to VCC, not GND.

Also, using this kind of fast chip without decoupling capacitor will probably result an unintended oscillator.

Comment: Yes, I notice the 4.7M was at GND and not VCC. Somehow I seem to make the initially bright LED dimmer, with the multimeter probe and my finger at the same time touching the wire. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

From the datasheets ([AD8561](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8561.pdf) and [LM393](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm193.pdf?ts=1640569642482)), you'll see that the devices are very different.  The AD8561 is a very capable modern device that costs $6 and the LM393 was designed in the '70s and costs $1; almost every parameter is different between them.  Here's a bit of a guide to what to look for for your (relatively undemanding) application that will hopefully help you get more familiar with reading datasheets.

The most obvious difference is that the LM393 is a dual comparator and the AD8561 is a single.  That's fine, since your circuit only needs one comparator anyways (the linked website leaves the inputs of the unused comparator floating, which is a bit of a faux pas).  The pinouts are obviously not identical so you'll have to switch them around to match the AD8561.

Next, check the supply voltage.  Both devices are capable of single supply operation at 5V - so far so good.  Digging further, the AD8561 is much more feature-rich than the LM393 - it includes a latch and complementary logic outputs.  The latch is not required and can be turned off (i.e. the outputs follow the input state) by connecting pin 5 to ground.

Now, look at output current.  You're driving a LED through a 330 ohm resistor from 5V, so I would expect LED current to be around 10mA.  The LM393 can source up to 20mA; the AD8561 is a bit more complicated. The logic "1" voltage is specified to be average 3.5V (minimum 2.4) at 3.2mA output current.  10mA is more than 3.2 so we have to dig a bit further.  Fig. 11 shows VOH dropping to 3.2V at an output current of 10mA.  Your LED will light but may be a bit dim.  The 330 ohm resistor could probably be dropped to about 200 ohms if you want it brighter.